# How to transform data from a custom projection in JTS?

Tags: java, coordinates, coordinate-system, jts-topology-suite

I have some data in [NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/nad_1983_stateplane_texas_central_fips_4203_feet/)

I wish to programmatically transform the coordinates to Lat long in WGS84 datum using JTS.

I know that JTS can transform the coordinates using the following code:

```
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;

CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:23032");

MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform( sourceGeometry, transform);
```

But my projection does not have an EPSG code.

How do I define the coordinate system in this case? How do I transform my data into EPSG:3857?

Comment: isn't that the same as http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2277/

Comment: @iant: Looks like it is pretty much the same, based on the projection parameters. Someone how I didn't find it. Somehow GDAL had a problem recognizing it.

Comment: in general all the state planes have an EPSG code you just need to look by state, datum and unit to work out which one

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this documentation of CRS http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html#well-known-text

It is possible to set the CRS from WKT. The documentation says:

> CoordinateReferenceSystem can also be defined by a text format
>   ((called “Well Known Text” or WKT). This is a standard provided by the
>   OGC and shows up in inside a shapefile “prj” file, or in a databases
>   such as PostGIS and Oracle.
>
> To parse WKT please use the CRS.parseWKT( txt ) method.

It is possible to get the WKT from the PRJ file or even from http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/nad_1983_stateplane_texas_central_fips_4203_feet/ogcwkt/

Once the CRS is set from the WKT, the rest of the process is as it was.